# How to add actions to the top part of a split ActionBar

Tags: android, split, android-actionbar

If an Android ActionBar is split into a top and a bottom portion using `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in the `Manifext.xml`,
is there a way to force some of the actions to be displayed in the top portion instead of having them all at the bottom?

Comment: Looks like the answer is "no" and was answered at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-items-on-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way of doing this. That said, the Action Bar custom view will appear in the upper bar, so you can just use that. You will lose some of the extras (toasts on long press), so you'll have to implement them yourself. That said, of you're using ActionBarSherlock, all the layouts and styles for a normal button are there, so you can just use those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  You can continue to use `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in your Manifest.xml.

You just also need to set:

```
// set the actionbar to use the custom view
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

//set the custom view to use
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_top);
```

Where `R.layout.custom_action_bar_top` would be a view that has all the buttons you wish to appear in the top action bar.

All the menu items that you want at the bottom, should be added as usual in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method of your activity.

Comment: Hi @immersion, this makes sense but have you tried it? Does it actually work that way?

Comment: Hi @fuzzybee, yeah when I needed to do this, I only needed a search bar up the top so I used:
`SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(searchView, new LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));`

If you want to see what it looks like, check out [SwishPix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.immersion.swishpix.free). The screenshot of the list of albums is an example of what it might look like.

Comment: With this solution you would have to reimplement the icon and title manually as well, so it won't be an easy drop-in solution.

Comment: Unless something has changed since I last looked, using the `setCustomView` approach doesn't remove the Title or 'Up/Home' Icon. You can just use them as usual.

Comment: Well when was the last time you checked? It appears to remove them on Android 4.~

Comment: I just checked in my app, compiled for 4.2, running on my android 4.3 Samsung S3. The title and home button are not removed and the SearchView appears at the top right.

Comment: In my app compiled for 4.4 and running on 4.4, this makes my app icon and activity title disappear. But adding DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME and DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE to setDisplayOptions brings them back.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to second Dylan Watson's solution, but with one improvement. 
For those who would like to keep the title, and not replace the entire actionBar with their new View, they use `getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)` , rather than `getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);` , as the latter will cause the new view to be the only view displayed in the actionbar. My code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(this);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(searchView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Confirmed, this enables the custom view without disabling the home button and title as in Dylan's answer. If the title still doesn't appear, it might be covered by the custom view; this answer provides some layout options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16517395/462162