# Split action bar with icons at top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I came across this thread  on how to split icons across the top and bottom action bars: [How to add actions to the top part of a split ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076346/how-to-add-actions-to-the-top-part-of-a-split-actionbar). My question is where do the methods mentioned in the first answer go (`setDisplayOptions` & `setCustomView`)?

Thanks!

Comment: in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

Comment: Glad to help. You can upvote or can accept the answer ;-) if its helpful to you thanks :-)

Comment: I was going to say I'd upvote/accept answer if it wasn't a comment- now i see your answer :)  cheers

Answer (score 2):

The two methods for which you are asking should go in

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

method. Read more about [onCreate method here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) .

Comment: I have another question for you if you're interested in answering- `onCreate` method is this: `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
     getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_top);
    }`

I created `custom_action_bar_top.xml` and added my icon item to it but I'm getting an error when I compile. Feeling a bit sheepish for asking.  I know this is really basic but I'm lost.

Comment: The two lines you have at bottom should be above `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Hi.  I've moved the custom function calls above the `setContentView` call and below the `super.create` call.  The error is caused by: "(...)Landroid/view/item;" not found

Comment: Have you added the jar or the library needed for that views?

Comment: Hmm. All I have added for the top action bar icons are: 1) the two method calls in my main activity; 2)cusom_action_bar_top.xml to the layout folder- this file has my item element in it

Comment: Sorry, the imports in the main activity are
`import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;`

Comment: Please have a look here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html section **Enabling the split action bar**

Comment: Not sure mate.  I read the entire article but didn't find any answers.  Lots of good resources there though :)