# Number in Action Bar like Gmail

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to display a data count in the top right corner of my Action Bar.

If I wouldn't be using a split action bar I would just create a TextView in the bar, but it's currently [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-on-the-top-and-bottom) to have items in the top Action Bar when you have split.

To clarify, what I mean is this:

[image: Gmail unread count]

Did Google use a different Action Bar implementation or is there a way to do this?
I think I remember reading about it, but I can't find how it was called.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use a custom view with your spinner and text view for the top AB and enable the  `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in the manifest declaration for your activity

```
//set the actionbar to use the custom view (can also be done with a style)
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

//set the custom view to use
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_ab);
```

Where `custom_ab.xml` is a layout with your ImageView, Spinner and TextView for the count.

Comment: The custom view of the ActionBar is supplemental to the bar itself, which is not entirely clear from the documentation. As such, this answer is basically all you need, though you forgot to mention that then you would call getActionBar().getCustomView() to retrieve the view when needed.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep the app icon + up affordance:

`getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);`

Comment: you won't need to create a spinner manually. you can still use the navigation list mode. just set `getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);` after the `setCustomView()` method call.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using ActionBar or like and update your app to use Toolbar which has a simple and much easy interface to do the everything you can think of. For reading about it use the  [Android Blog][1]

[1]: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html for the pre lolipop apps.