# Can you split ActionBarSherlock items specifically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Split Action Bar with Action Items on the top and bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-on-the-top-and-bottom)

I am trying to use the ActionBarSherlock library on my application. I would like to have a Title and two unclickable icons in the top bar, with 4 remaining actions on the bottom bar. I have put `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in my AndroidManifest, but it seems that I have no power over which icons go where.

**EDIT**

By which icons go where, I mean that if the `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` call is used, **ALL** of the actions are moved to a bottom bar. If I do not use it, all of the actions remain on the top bar.

Comment: No, that is not possible. If you set `splitActionBarWhenNarrow`, all icons will go to the bottom, you can't leave some at the top. See this answer: [Android Split Action Bar with Action Items on the top and bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8609144/1018177)