# Action bar force split tabs and action mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionmode

How to force an `ActionBar` to split with tabs (at the `top`) and `ActionMode` (at the `bottom`)? 
 `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` doesn't help (I'm trying on a widescreen emulator)

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-on-the-top-and-bottom

Answer (score 2):

You'll have better luck testing this in portrait mode, since splitActionBarWhenNarrow is explicitly for narrow (i.e. portrait) orientations.

This design is on purpose - when in landscape mode your vertical real estate is more limited, so it makes sense to make the most use of the greater width of a single action bar rather than taking up twice that space (top and bottom).  While the link Ethan provides will lead you to some custom implementation, I suggest reconsidering the design to follow Android design patterns as much as possible.  Deviate when you have a really good reason, of course.