# Android ActionBar: collapsible SearchView with action button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

How to build `ActionBar` with collapsible search view with single action item visible, when search view is expanded? To be more descriptive, this is what I need:

[image]
Note that there are other menu items and `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` is defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I tried to set up custom search item layout:

> menu.xml

```html
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/search" />
```

> actionbar_search.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="@string/search_hint" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
        android:src="@drawable/content_new"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But by default search view takes all available width and button is not visible. I don't know how to force `SearchView` to fill all available space between app icon and menu item. All I found is `android:maxWidth` property, but this only allows to hardcoded dimension, and I'm looking for some more flexible solution. I tried also `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_view"` with no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After considering the suggestions from comments, many googling and testing succeeded in obtaining the desired effect. I'm not proud of this solution but it works, it's not too complicated and should be enough for this case.

In resume what I did:

1. Placed `SearchView` with custom "add item" button in `customView` of `ActionBar`.
2. Removed `collapseActionView` and `android:actionLayout` from search item in `menu.xml`
3. Collapsing/expanding `SearchView` programmatically.

Some code to better understand what I did. Maybe this can be useful for someone.

> menu.xml

```html
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/search" />

// ... other menu items
```

> actionbar_search.xml

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
        android:src="@drawable/content_new"
        android:title="@string/add_item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```android
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_search);
    actionBarCustomView = ab.getCustomView();
    searchView = ((SearchView) actionBarCustomView.findViewById(R.id.search_view));
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            searchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // ...
        case R.id.menu_search:
            if (searchView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                searchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                searchView.setMaxWidth(abCustomView.getWidth() - addButton.getWidth());
                searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchView.setIconified(false);
            }
            break;
        // ...
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (searchView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your above solution but it is not working at all. In fact I am not able to see any of the action item.

Comment: Can you post fragments of your code (eg. as gist)? I spent few days figuring it out and testing, think I can help.

Comment: where should I post my code fragment ?? I can't post my problem code here as a comment. 
Also, could you please help me to achieve this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947557/sherlockactionbar-with-autocompletetextview-and-other-items?noredirect=1#comment22723847_15947557

Comment: You can use, for example https://gist.github.com/ for posting code fragments and paste link here. If I find some time today I will try to help in your question.

Comment: Just so you know that its much easier to achieve this by using RelativeLayout inside actionbar_search.xml and simply give imageButton alignParentRight=true. Also you need to add  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_item" to your SearchView. Just tested, works just fine

Answer (score 2):

You can do it only using yourmenu.xml.

Set your other menu icon to always show as an action.
Your menu.xml should look like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/search"
/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/your_other_menu_id"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/your_other_menu_ic"
 />
```

Comment: Tried this approach. As I mentioned there are other menu items and all of them overflows to bottom actionbar. And I need this one add action always placed in right top corner.

Comment: The detail in this case is the split action bar, not the collapsable search view.
Check the link bellow. It is not possible to set this behavior using native objects. You'll need to create your own customized action bar.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-on-the-top-and-bottom

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I already tried this one too. Custom ActionBar gives me custom view when SearchView is collapsed. Then I have my single button at the top bar and those form menu.xml at the bottom.

The problem is when SearchView is expanded. I need to force it to fill all available space between app icon and single action item. I tried understand what is happening in `onMeasure()` of SearchView class but not exactly understand what I can do with this, and if it is, at all, a right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to create your own action view class? May be you can simply extend SearchView class but I'm not sure. In resume, what you can do is:
1. Create a class that implements CollapsibleActionView (may be extending SearchView);
Where you can implement onActionViewExpanded() adding a button for your menu item after the TextEdit.
2. set this class as the action view class on your menu item:
android:actionViewClass="your.package.YourSearchView"

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do it like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
     searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
     searchView.setIconified(true); //to be opened collapsed
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_search:
            searchView.setIconified(false);// to Expand the SearchView when clicked
            return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

And at search item in menu.xml make

**showAsAction="always"**

Note: I am using  android.support.v7.widget.SearchView  but in your case it doesn't matter

Comment: @salma yes you right android.support.v7.widget.SearchView and android.widget.searchview its matter a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just a change menu xml. showaction prefix to your app name

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/search"
/>

</menu>
```