# Action bar sherlock : two bars ? (menu at bottom / search bar on top)

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, searchbar

In my application, I have created a class Base_Activity extending SherlockFragmentActivity in which I have defined an action bar this way (it is a menu bar with three different items):

```
public class Base_Activity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
private ActionBar mActionBar;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    case R.id.map:
         Intent ii = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            ii.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(ii);
        return true;
    case R.id.favorites:
         Intent iii = new Intent(this, FavoritesListView.class);
            iii.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(iii);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
} }
```

Then I have added this line to set this bar in the bottom of my application :

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

It's working well, so far I don't have any problems : I have my bottom action bar with listener for every button.
I now want to add a top action bar, with a SearchBar (or SearchWidget) and a item opening a submenu in the up-right corner.

My problem is now : at the top of every activity, instead of the useless bar with the name of each activity, I want to have another top bar with :
1/ A search bar
2/ An icon opening a sub-menu in the up-right corner.

Unfortunately, I often read that it's not really possible but many application do use this. I am really having a hard time finding how to add my search bar, which doesn't make sense : I know how to write my query method, I have my databaseAdapter and Helper class, so basically it's just about displaying a simple search bar on the top, putting a listener and sending my query to the database and then display a list view.

Does anyone know something which can do the trick to keep an action bar on the bottom and have a search bar also on the top ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422505/android-actionbar-collapsible-searchview-with-action-button). I think will answer for your first question. Second is very similar to this what I need.

Comment: Thanks, took a quick look and it might indeed help.