# MenuItem's onclick method is not called if menu item showAsAction="always"

Tags: android, menuitem, android-menu

Im having trouble with the menu items.

I have a search view in my menu, and I set `OnMenuItemClickListener` on the item in my `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

[image]

and my menu xml: the showAsAction attribute is set to **"always"**
[image]

however, if I click the search icon, nothing happen, the toast did not show up.

[image]

strange thing is if I set showAsAction="always|collapseActionView", if will work, but the search icon is gone and replaced by "search" text.

it works, toast is shown.

[image]

but the icon is gone

[image]

********************edit****************************************

[image]

Comment: Also can you tell me whether this is a toolbar or the default action bar provided by android?

Comment: take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong syntax for your menu. Kindly replace you menu inflater/handler code with this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourActivity_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.search) {
        //Handle the onClick with Toast over here.
        //IF you have multiple options then replace if with a switch() statement
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

As far as the icon is concerned, you have specify the icon attribute in the xml file by adding android:icon="@drawable/YOU_ICON_HERE"

EDIT: Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html You are supposed to keep  android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" for this to work. The only change you now have to make is add an android:icon attribute to the xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

or android.widget.v7 support depending on your android version you wish to support

Comment: Hi Varun, I used toolbar to replace the default actionbar. I tried your method, but its not working either... the onOptionsItemSelected() method is not called at all. Is it because I used toolbar?

Comment: Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setHomeUpEnabled();   Add these lines and show me your initial lines of onCreate()

Comment: hi Varun, Ive updated my post for those codes. thank you

Comment: add  if(getSupportActionBar!=null){ setHomeButtonEnabled(true) } to get rid of the null pointer error. Is it working now? Also you can change the initial icon, home button icon, Title and add a subtitle programmatically.

Comment: hi ive added         getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
and its not working still....

Comment: Firstly, is the text "search" showing properly? Have you added the code for the icon? And when you click on it, is a ripple effect being observed?

Comment: if I set the showAsAction to always, the search title is not showing but the defualt icon, but if i set to always|collapseActionView, it will show the title instead of the icon

Comment: Then just remove the Title attribute and see how it works. Google recommends to keep it as always|collapseActionView

Comment: i cant remove the title attribute, if i remove it says "menu item should have a title attr".... the point is the showAsAction attribute, if always|collapseActionView it works but the icon is gone , title take place , if always only, the listener does not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422505/android-actionbar-collapsible-searchview-with-action-button  
Long solution but this OP has been able to achieve this. If it works do accept my answer :)

Comment: thats not what im concerned, im wondering why the showAsAction will resutl in the disability of the onClicked method....anyway...i upvote your answer,