# Split Action Bar only in Action Mode (CAB)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

It is possible to have a split Action Bar **only** in Action Mode?

My application have only the top action bar, but it's Contextual Action Bar needs to be splitted in two (top/bottom).

I found this:

> The contextual action bar is not necessarily associated with the action bar. They operate independently, even though the contextual action bar visually overtakes the action bar position.

on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB. So i think it's possible, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident it's not possible - and even if it is - i would cringe to see the hack.

The cab is a crafty beast that offers a lot of convenience out of the box but doesn't like to be tampered with.

The platform takes care of you fantastically by placing a CAB at the bottom if required or collapsing items , but as far as UI designs go, you should avoid relying on the bottom bar.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609144/1593156 .