# Creating custom bottom ActionBar / Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I found this great answer for creating custom action bars:

[Android Split Action Bar with Action Items on the top and bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-on-the-top-and-bottom)

I'm a bit confused on how they formed the bottom bar with the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.browser_main, menu);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(
        R.id.layout_item).getActionView();

View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.media_bottombar, null);

relativeLayout.addView(inflatedView);

return true;
```

}

So the `browser_main` is a menu with a list of items? I'm not sure how the RelativeLayout comes into play. I would like to implement my own RelativeLayout to the bottom bar but I'm not sure how it works. What would be included in the `browser_main.xml` and `media_bottombar.xml`. Also, what is the `R.id.layout_item`?

Answer (score 0):

R.id.layout_item is the xml layout file called "layout_item.xml" located under res/layout/ .

If I were I would disable top bar and bottom bar. then you can use nested layouts to simulate top and bottom bars. this is much easier. but not the best solution...

Comment: Link or description on how to do that?