# Put action on top & have split actionbar at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar-compat

I use ActionBarCompat (So my Action Bar works on API 8 and above.)
And I also use this so I can have split Action Bar.

> android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

Now I have all my actions in the bottom, but I want to take the search-action and put it up on the right corner.

[image]

I have tried to Google this, but I don't find any solutions to this.
(Every link seems to be old).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609144/1584654)

As suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587095/1584654) you can just use a workaround for this issue.

Comment: Okey, thank you. Cuz it didnt work with the :
_____________________________________________________________________________________
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.actionbar,
            null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view);